# Errores TS2339 y TS2322 en mi sistema de usuarios basado en Angular y PHP

Tags: angular

Necesito hacer un sistema de usuarios para angular, con mysql. La verdad es que nunca he hecho ninguno y busco algo de luz para saber por dónde empezar. Mi API está hecha en PHP.

Estuve siguiendo el siguiente tutorial:

- https://javiercobossanz.com/2017/05/18/angular-implementando-login/#.XRxJ-I-UWUk

La verdad es que me hace el login y todo perfecto, por lo que decidí continuar con el siguiente tutorial, que es obtener los datos a través de una API, pero me tira error supongo que será por la versión de Angular.

Este es el siguiente tutorial que he seguido:

- https://javiercobossanz.com/2017/05/27/angular-consumiendo-la-api-para-el-login/#.XRxKqY-UWUk

En el servicio importa lo siguiente:

```
import {Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions, RequestMethod} from "@angular/http";
```

En la parte del servicio donde le mando para hacer el login es donde tengo el error el código original es éste:

```
  login(user) : Promise<any> {
    var usertologin =new UserService(user.usertologin,user.password);
    let headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
    let body = JSON.stringify({user});
    let options = new RequestOptions();
    return this._http.post(environment.apiUrl + environment.loginModuleUrl, body, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: headers,
        body: body,
        url: environment.apiUrl + environment.loginModuleUrl
      })
      .toPromise()
      .then(response => this.handleSuccess(response))
      .catch(error=> this.handleError(error));
  }
```

Yo lo edité cambiando el `RequestOptions` por `HttpHeaders()` y poniendo el siguiente `import`:

```
login(user) : Promise<any> {
    var usertologin =new UserService(user.usertologin,user.password);
    let headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
    let body = JSON.stringify({user});
    let options = new HttpHeaders();
    return this._http.post(environment.apiUrl + environment.loginModuleUrl, body, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: headers,
        body: body,
        url: environment.apiUrl + environment.loginModuleUrl
      })
      .toPromise()
      .then(response => this.handleSuccess(response))
      .catch(error=> this.handleError(error));
}
```

Y en el `import` puse lo siguiente:

```
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
```

Aún así me tira los siguientes errores:

```
 ERROR in src/app/services/login.service.ts(43,41): error TS2339: Property 'apiUrl' does not exist on type '{ production: boolean; }'.
src/app/services/login.service.ts(43,62): error TS2339: Property 'loginModuleUrl' does not exist on type '{ production: boolean; }'.
src/app/services/login.service.ts(45,10): error TS2322: Type 'Headers' is not assignable to type 'HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[]; }'.
  Type 'Headers' is not assignable to type '{ [header: string]: string | string[]; }'.
    Index signature is missing in type 'Headers'.
src/app/services/login.service.ts(47,27): error TS2339: Property 'apiUrl' does not exist on type '{ production: boolean; }'.
src/app/services/login.service.ts(47,48): error TS2339: Property 'loginModuleUrl' does not exist on type '{ production: boolean; }'.
```

Se me olvidaba comentar mi versión de Angular es la 7.

Comment: ¿No has intentado hacer nada? ¿Qué te falla? Si no especificas un poco tu pregunta se cerrará por ser demasiado amplia.

Comment: Para servirte de orientación, tengo un pequeño ejemplo en github: [https://github.com/ojgarciab/angularjs-slim-crud](https://github.com/ojgarciab/angularjs-slim-crud). Lo estoy portando a Angular.io, pero aún no he tenido tiempo para avanzar en la nueva versión. Espero que, al menos, te sirva para entender algunos conceptos.

Comment: Holaa, edite el post para poner lo que he probado durante estas horas, la verdad esque estoy super perdido con esto y me tiene amargado

Comment: Vale, veo tu problema gracias al mensaje de error. **NO has definido** `apiURL` y `loginModuleUrl` en `environments/environment.ts` como una propiedad más de `environment`. Parece que el autor del tutorial debió olvidar u omitir esa parte.

Comment: Muchas gracias OscarGarcia, ya añnadi la URL de la API pero sabrias que debo añadir en LoginModule supongo que el modulo login pero como pongo la url de dicho modulo

Comment: No entiendo lo nuevo que me estás preguntando. En `apiUrl` debes poner la URL base del API (`https://miweb.com/api/v3` por ejemplo) y en `loginModuleUrl` parece que debes proporcionar la ruta relativa a la base en la que está la llamada al módulo de login (por ejemplo `/login.php`).

Comment: En mi caso sería /login supongo ya que tengo un componente para el login verdad? Ya solo me tira un error del headers ERROR in src/app/services/login.service.ts(48,10): error TS2322: Type 'Headers' is not assignable to type 'HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[]; }'.
  Type 'Headers' is not assignable to type '{ [header: string]: string | string[]; }'.
    Index signature is missing in type 'Headers'.

Comment: Tienes un error en `let headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});`, sería `let headers = new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});`.

Comment: En cuanto me confirmes que esto último soluciona del todo tus problemas redactaré la respuesta con enlace a la documentación para explicarte cada cosa detalladamente.

Comment: ME sigue tirando error, estoy montando una prueba un segundo y te lo paso muchiismas gracias Oscar enserio

Comment: [Para evitar extender la conversación en la pregunta, continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95668/discussion-between-oscargarcia-and-miguel-angel-martin).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debemos separar los dos tipos de mensajes de error que te están apareciendo.

Por un lado tienes estos mensajes de `error TS2339`:

```
error TS2339: Property 'apiUrl' does not exist on type '{ production: boolean; }'.
error TS2339: Property 'loginModuleUrl' does not exist on type '{ production: boolean; }'.
```

En esos mensajes se te informa de que intentas acceder a las propiedades `apiUrl` y `loginModuleUrl` de `environment` sin haber sido definido en `environments/environment.ts` ([datos exactos obtenidos del chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95668/discussion-between-oscargarcia-and-miguel-angel-martin)):

```
export const environment = {
    apiUrl:'http://localhost/clinica-backend/index.php',
    loginModuleUrl:'/login',
    production: false
};
```

En segundo lugar tienes este mensaje `error TS2322`:

```
error TS2322: Type 'Headers' is not assignable to type 'HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[]; }'.
  Type 'Headers' is not assignable to type '{ [header: string]: string | string[]; }'.
```

Te está informando que el campo `headers` espera un campo de tipo `HttpHeaders` o, en su lugar, una serie de cabeceras proporcionadas explícitamente de la forma `{ [header: string]: string | string[]; }` ([ver documentación](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient#post)):

> options: { headers?: HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[]; }; ...

En tu caso estás proporcionando una variable de tipo `Header` que no puede convertirse a ninguno de los tipos soportados, por lo que la única solución es generar el tipo requerido adecuado:

```
login(user) : Promise<any> {
  var usertologin = new UserService(user.usertologin, user.password);
  /* Aquí estaba el problema, usamos HttpHeaders en vez de Headers */
  let headers = new HttpHeaders(
    {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
  );
  let body = JSON.stringify({user});
  return this._http.post(
    environment.apiUrl + environment.loginModuleUrl,
    body,
    {
      headers: headers,
    }
  )
    .toPromise()
    .then(response => this.handleSuccess(response))
    .catch(error => this.handleError(error));
}
```